# find command how to combine OR and AND

Tags: linux, find

I would like to find all php and js files inside a directory and exclude one of sub directory.
I may have to exclude more than one sub directory in the future.

I tried :

```
find /home/jul/here -type f -iname "*.php" -o -iname "*.js" ! -path "/home/jul/here/exclude/*"
```

Problem is that it is excluding only js file from /home/jul/here/exclude.

Is there a way to put some kind of parentheses?

find (something OR something else) AND exclude THIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /home/jul/here -type f \( -iname "*.php" -o -iname "*.js" \) ! -path "/home/jul/here/exclude/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the exclusion pattern after each group of files. So something like this should work:

```
find /home/jul/here -type f -iname "*.php" ! -path "/home/jul/here/exclude/*" -o -iname "*.js" ! -path "/home/jul/here/exclude/*"
```

Or maybe better with a variable:

```
EXCLUDE=/home/jul/here/exclude
find /home/jul/here -type f -iname "*.php" ! -path "$EXCLUDE/*" -o -iname "*.js" ! -path "$EXCLUDE/*"
```

Comment: thanks but I just find how to use these parentheses in my answer